# How can I identify where Yii application execution is ending?

Tags: yii, yii1.x

**Prerequisites:** Running on Ubuntu. Using Apache. Yii version is printing 1.1.2.

**My question:**

I'm helping a friend out with a web app where his application developer abruptly quit. The problem is, I'm somewhat green with PHP and COMPLETELY green with Yii. I'm having a difficult time setting up a test server using the existing code. What's happening is the index.php code calls a CWebApplication-derived class, but the run() method never returns, and all I get is a blank page (this obviously doesn't happen in production). I'm trying to understand how to identify what's happening, and where the execution is just dying.

First, let me say that I ran http:///yii/requirements/index.php, and the requirements checker claimed I had the minimum requirements to run.

Second, my index.php looks like this:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);

// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/yii/framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';
$gapi = dirname(__FILE__) . '/protected/vendors/Google/autoload.php';

// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

require_once($gapi);
require_once($yii);
/*
 * Manage URL Uppercase or lowercase
 */

$manage_url_path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/protected/components/ManageUrl.php';
require_once( $manage_url_path );
$create_web_application = new ManageUrl($config);
$create_web_application->run();
```

When $create_web_application->run() executes, it never returns (printing after it prints nothing), and I get just a blank page.

This class (ManageUrl) overrides createController, but so far it feels like execution never makes it to this function. Placing any print() statements in there shows nothing. $Yii::log() also shows nothing. There's nothing in the application.log under /runtime. Apache's error logs are showing nothing too.  It's as if code execution is just going into a black hole.

One final thing to note: I've got mod_rewrite enabled on the server. I followed this outdated howto on DigitalOcean to get things started (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-yii-php-framework-on-ubuntu-12-04).

Can you advise me on how to figure out what's going on with this application and why I just get a blank page? I need to figure out where the code execution is going and subsequently dying.

Comment: Blank page probably means fatal error. I would double check if you have error reporting enabled with correct level, and then check logs again. Also Yii 1.1.2 is pretty ancient, you should update framework to something more recent.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. The problem is the previous developer(s) left  A LOT to be desired in terms of structuring this thing well. At the moment the most pressing issue is getting the patient breathing. 

Thanks for your help. From your experience, should the createController function of the CWebApplication-derviced ManageUrl class be executing? Is there something earlier than that function in the pipeline I could hook and debug? 

I'm pressing because I've got the error logging setup (I think) as verbose as I can get it. The issue is this class just appears to not execute.

Comment: `ManageUrl` is not a standard class, I have no idea what it is doing. In normal `CWebApplication` you should be able to track calls pretty easily (`run()` -> `processRequest()` -> ...).